# Filtering pandas dataframe values using different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've two data frames in which column contains values like

```
df1:
    Col     Actual
    SA~all  all
    SA~bme  beyond media engagers
    SA~bsv  beyond site visitors
    SA~blk  blink
    SA~beng brand.com media engagers
    SA~by   buy
    SA~cs   choose
    SA~tgm  gen-targeted mass
```

and another data frame

```
df2:
Name
CN~QLED8KLOPromotion_PD~1200x628PPLProspecting_MK~es_CH~soc_MD~c_AD~ss1x1_DT~cross_FM~sban_PB~fcbk_SZ~1200x628_RT~cpc_TG~bhv_SA~tgm_VV~dc_IT~soc_TS~IPES_FF~None _PH~laun_MK~es_YQ~19q2_BS~im_PR~tv_SB~brand_OB~awa_PK~CTR_FS~lo_CP~
CN~QLED8KLOPromotion_PD~1200x628PPLProspecting_MK~es_CH~soc_MD~c_AD~ss1x1_DT~cross_FM~sban_PB~fcbk_SZ~1200x628_RT~cpc_TG~bhv_SA~tgm_VV~dc_IT~soc_TS~IPES_FF~None _PH~laun_MK~es_YQ~19q2_BS~im_PR~tv_SB~brand_OB~awa_PK~CTR_FS~lo_CP~
CN~QLED8KLOPromotion_PD~1200x628PPLProspecting_MK~es_CH~soc_MD~c_AD~ss1x1_DT~cross_FM~sban_PB~fcbk_SZ~1200x628_RT~cpc_TG~bhv_SA~tgm_VV~dc_IT~soc_TS~IPES_FF~None _PH~laun_MK~es_YQ~19q2_BS~im_PR~tv_SB~brand_OB~awa_PK~CTR_FS~lo_CP~
CN~QLED8KLOPromotion_PD~1200x628PPLProspecting_MK~es_CH~soc_MD~c_AD~ss1x1_DT~cross_FM~sban_PB~fcbk_SZ~1200x628_RT~cpc_TG~bhv_SA~tgm_VV~dc_IT~soc_TS~IPES_FF~None _PH~laun_MK~es_YQ~19q2_BS~im_PR~tv_SB~brand_OB~awa_PK~CTR_FS~lo_CP~
CN~QLED8KLOPromotion_PD~1200x628PPLProspecting_MK~es_CH~soc_MD~c_AD~ss1x1_DT~cross_FM~sban_PB~fcbk_SZ~1200x628_RT~cpc_TG~bhv_SA~tgm_VV~dc_IT~soc_TS~IPES_FF~None _PH~laun_MK~es_YQ~19q2_BS~im_PR~tv_SB~brand_OB~awa_PK~CTR_FS~lo_CP~
CN~QLED8KLOPromotion_PD~1200x628PPLProspecting_MK~es_CH~soc_MD~c_AD~ss1x1_DT~cross_FM~sban_PB~fcbk_SZ~1200x628_RT~cpc_TG~bhv_SA~tgm_VV~dc_IT~soc_TS~IPES_FF~None _PH~laun_MK~es_YQ~19q2_BS~im_PR~tv_SB~brand_OB~awa_PK~CTR_FS~lo_CP~
CN~QLED8KLOPromotion_PD~1200x628PPLProspecting_MK~es_CH~soc_MD~c_AD~ss1x1_DT~cross_FM~sban_PB~fcbk_SZ~1200x628_RT~cpc_TG~bhv_SA~tgm_VV~dc_IT~soc_TS~IPES_FF~None _PH~laun_MK~es_YQ~19q2_BS~im_PR~tv_SB~brand_OB~awa_PK~CTR_FS~lo_CP~
CN~QLED8KLOPromotion_PD~1200x628PPLProspecting_MK~es_CH~soc_MD~c_AD~ss1x1_DT~cross_FM~sban_PB~fcbk_SZ~1200x628_RT~cpc_TG~bhv_SA~tgm_VV~dc_IT~soc_TS~IPES_FF~None _PH~laun_MK~es_YQ~19q2_BS~im_PR~tv_SB~brand_OB~awa_PK~CTR_FS~lo_CP~
CN~QLED8KLOPromotion_PD~1200x628PPLProspecting_MK~es_CH~soc_MD~c_AD~ss1x1_DT~cross_FM~sban_PB~fcbk_SZ~1200x628_RT~cpc_TG~bhv_SA~tgm_VV~dc_IT~soc_TS~IPES_FF~None _PH~laun_MK~es_YQ~19q2_BS~im_PR~tv_SB~brand_OB~awa_PK~CTR_FS~lo_CP~
```

I am looking for a way to find rows that contain `df1` values and add a new column in `df2` containing values from `df1['Actual']` column.

Is it possible? I tried using `numpy` `select` which I think not working as expected.

Comment: In the examples you showed above - are there any items in `df2` that should have matched with `df1`?

Comment: @AnthonyR Yes, just edited with available value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you mean by "contain df1 values" but for now I will assume you mean `Name` column in df2 contains one of the strings (ie has substring) in the `Col` column in df1, and then if it does so, add the respective `Actual` value from df1 in another column in df2

One way to do this would be using `df.apply`

```
def findSubstring(bigString, ss = list(df1["Col"]):
    for x in ss:
        if x in bigString:
            return x
    return "NO MATCHING STRINGS"

def getVal(row, otherdf = df1):
    substring = findSubstring(row["Actual"])
    if substring != "NO MATCHING STRINGS":
        return list(df1[df1["Col"] == substring]["Actual"])[0]

df2["Actual"] = df2.apply(lambda x: getVal(x), axis =1)
```

There might be a faster way, but df.apply can be adjusted for anything you need

Let me know if this answers your question.